# UIScrollView is not scrolling contents

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uilabel, uitextview

This is what I want to do:

[image]

I set number of line of label to 0, even I replaced UILabel with TextView but even it doesn't expand when has more line than it's height. Then scrollview not scrolls

What should to do with AutoLayout?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you constraints set right.

For example, select your scroll view, show the size inspector, you will see like this the below image. Make sure the scroll view can refer height(Same as width). If you can't see it, it's your subviews of the scrollview constraints issue, then check one by one. Besides this you will have to set the top, bottom, leading trailing of the scrollView to the super view. I assume you have done it.

[image]

Comment: I think it's not scrollview's fualt, dynamic label is not updating it's height to push down below labels

Comment: Check one of you subviews, some necessary constraints are missing. Also set this property ```preferredMaxLayoutWidth``` for the dynamic label.

Comment: I realized what is main problem, for last label which has fixed height I set constraints for top & bottom spacing. Top spacing is necessary to push down it. I use bottom spacing to push down superview's height which is a UIView, what should i do to now? because this causes dyanimc label's height becomes fixed

Comment: I spent 2 days for this issue, now it's not scrolling

Comment: Not clear what you said. Maybe you can share some code or your project. Use the way in my answer can figure it out.
You can set fixed height for any static label but the dynamic one. You also can try to set a "Larger than (>=)" height constraint for you dynamic label.

Comment: I found out why label is not expanding, because I set top spacing and bottom spacing for last Label, so it prevents "dynamic label" from expanding, look in picture. now if I dont set bottom spacing for last label it will expand content of dynamic label, but scrolling won't work

Comment: How do you know ```because I set top spacing and bottom spacing for last Label, so it prevents "dynamic label" from expanding```? Seems no reason.

Comment: I tried and this happens.I should mention these all are placed inside uiview,  my Viewcontroller is like this:   View=>scrollview=>UiView(image,label,label,label.dynamic label,label);

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that could be setup the wrong way and its hard to know from your description.
You can set contentSize of the scrollView in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Try something like this (you can play with the numbers you set for the size, make sure the numbers are larger then the screen size):

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height + 300)
    }
```

This may help to figure whats wrong.